# Winsocket resv buffer mistake

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, winsock

Trying to understand working of winsocket with Visual C++
Here the my code:

```
while (true) {
    char l[1];
    recv(tsock.sock, l, 1, 0);
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    if (!l)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

But what i got when tryin to get google.com:80 http get query:

```
Connected
Sending request to host
H╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
T╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠☺
T╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠☻
P╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♥
/ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♦
1╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♣
.╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♠
0╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
3╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
0╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

2╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♂
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♀
F╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
o╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠♫
u╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠☼
n╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠►
d╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠◄
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠↕

╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠‼
C╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠¶
...
```

There lot of trash recived. But when i change declaration of buffer form 1 cell to 2 and more everything seem to bee work greate.
Code

```
while (true) {
    char l[2];
    memset(&l, 0, sizeof(l));
    recv(tsock.sock, l, 1, 0);
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    if (!l)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

And result:

```
ConnectedSending request to hostHTTP / 1.0 302 Found
Cache - Control: private
Content - Type : text / html; charset = UTF - 8
Location: http ://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=r_RPU4yzJ8GdwAOWjoDoAQ
Content - Length : 258
Date : Thu, 17 Apr 2014 15 : 35 : 11 GMT
Server : GFE / 2.0
Alternate - Protocol : 80 : quic

<HTML><HEAD><meta http - equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved< / TITLE>< / HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved< / H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF = "http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=r_RPU4yzJ8GdwAOWjoDoAQ">here< / A>
.
< / BODY>< / HTML>
```

What the deal of this thing?

Comment: Why are you flushing the stream buffer after every character?
Wouldn't std::cout << l << '\n' be much better?

Answer (score 1):

The major problem here is that you use an array of characters (even if it's just an array of a single character), which the output operator interprets as a string. And as you should know, all strings needs to be terminated by the special character `'\0'`, which can be anywhere in memory after the character you read.

Instead you should use a single `char` variable, and use the address-of operator when receiving:

```
char l;
recv(tsock.sock, &l, 1, 0);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a larger array and use the returned value from [`recv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to know where to put the string terminator:

```
char l[1025];  // 1024 +1 for terminator
int rsz = recv(tsock.sock, l, sizeof(l) - 1, 0);  // -1 for terminator
if (rsz > 0)
{
    l[rsz] = '\0';  // Terminate string
    std::cout << l << std::flush;
}
else
{
    // Handle closed connection, or errors
}
```

I actually recommend this second option. Not only will you then check for errors and closed connection, it's also much more effective.